# How to close modal on next click after open?

Tags: jquery

I have the link with class `control` on which rises div with class `popup`. The problem is on how to close this div on the next click if this click is outside the div? At the moment this two events fires at the same moment and as a result modal don't appear.  How to close this modal only on the next click.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('body').on('click', function(event){
        var menu_popup = jQuery('div.popup[data-open-status="true"]');

        if(menu_popup.has(event.target).length === 0)
            menu_popup.hide().attr('data-open-status', 'false');
    });

    jQuery('a.control').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('div.popup').show().attr('data-open-status', 'true');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the click event doesn't bubble up the dom. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25xFu/2)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("a.control").click(function (e) {
        jQuery("div.popup").show().attr('data-open-status', 'true');
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    jQuery(document).click(function (e) {
        var menu_popup = jQuery('div.popup[data-open-status="true"]');
        if (menu_popup.has(e.target).length === 0) menu_popup.hide().attr('data-open-status', 'false');
    });

    // Add a stopPropagation so that when a user clicks in the div, the event doesn't bubble up to "document"
    jQuery("div.popup").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

But it appears to me that you can leave out the data-attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/25xFu/1/

```
$("a.control").click(function (e) {
    $("div.popup").slideToggle("fast");

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($("div.popup").is(":visible") && !$("div.popup").is(e.target)) {
        $("div.popup").slideUp("fast");
    }
});

$("div.popup").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```